# raspberry pi media center in production environment

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I'm building a machine that's like a kiosk computer for displaying slideshow and video, etc. Right now I'm using a Intel NUC but it's a bit expensive. So I'm looking at the RPi 3. With that I have the following questions:

1. This is going to be a production system. After reading up, I plan to go with a class 10 SD card for system. I'll mount the root file system read only and turn off swap. Is this good enough?
2. I need a hard drive for storing pictures, etc. I know there is WD PiDrive. But housing is a problem. Is there a good case that works with both?

Comment: 1. You can only know if you give very specific details. And it really depends on how far you can optimalize your stuff.
2. You could use one very big USB stick. Or use a bigger SD card. Or use a network storage.

Answer (score 0):

I actually created a similar setup with my RPi2. I hope it helps.

I used the [Pi Video Looper available from adafruit.](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-video-looper/overview) If you're in your RPi's terminal, you can apt-get it.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y git
git clone https://github.com/adafruit/pi_video_looper.git
```

Once that is done, enter

```
cd pi_video_looper
sudo ./install.sh
```

It may take a few minutes, but once it's done your monitor should automatically show a "Insert USB Drive..." message.

Video Looper will play any media on your USB drive alphabetically after a few seconds. It's set to run on boot, so if you're creating a dedicated box it's perfect. However, you can disable it if you want to use your pi for multiple applications. To run it again, just run the installation script again.

There is a lot more on the site I linked to. Specifically, using the SD card to house your media. You'll need to edit the config, which is pretty straight forward, to point the looper to your media directory. There's more on the site, but essentially you're changing the following in **video_looper.ini** (you can either edit this by opening the file on another pc, or use the Pi's nano editor).

To use nano, open the terminal and enter

```
nano /boot/video_looper.ini
```

Scroll down and change the following:

From:

```
file_reader = usb_drive
#file_reader = directory
```

To:

```
#file_reader = usb_drive
file_reader = directory
```

To change the path to your directory, scroll down until you see the following and change the "path = " to where you stored your media. In my case I kept my fiels in /home/pi/media. Clever, I know.

```
# Directory file reader configuration follows.
[directory]

# The path to search for movies when using the directory file reader.
path = /home/pi
```

Hope this helps!

A few notes:
- I had a wireless keyboard already, which came in handy since you'll be working in Raspbian. There are "instant on" options out there, but I preferred keeping my RPi in "multi-tool" mode, rather than turn it into a dedicated box.
- Storage / case was also an issue. I ended up using a 32Gb class 10 Mirco SD card, which had enough storage for my media and the OS. No extra drives necessary. You can now get class 10 Micro SD cards up to 200Gb. So, unless you're playing multiple feature length movies, you should be fine.